# How to run a single .spec.ts file in an angular-cli project?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli

What is the recommended method for running unit tests on a single component or service?

I can temporarily modify `tests.ts` to only load a single `.spec.ts` file, but this seems very hacky.  There doesn't appear to be an option for `ng test` that does this.

Edit: This question is answered here: [Running a single test file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132933/running-a-single-test-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a single test file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132933/running-a-single-test-file)

Comment: @tilo That question was posted after this one, so technically I think it's the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using fdescribe on your root describe block in the spec?