# Running a single test file

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-cli, karma-runner

Is there a way to run `ng test` for a single file instead of for the entire test suite?  Ideally, I'd like to get the quickest possible feedback loop when I'm editing a file, but `karma` executes the whole suite on each save, which is a bit slow when you build up a big enough test suite.

---

This is different from [How to execute only one test spec with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683673/how-to-execute-only-one-test-spec-with-angular-cli) in that that question is about running an individual spec.  This is about running an individual file.  The solution involves the same Jasmine spec feature, but the nature of the question is slightly different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute only one test spec with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683673/how-to-execute-only-one-test-spec-with-angular-cli)

Comment: You can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683673/how-to-execute-only-one-test-spec-with-angular-cli/58119974#58119974

Comment: You can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683673/how-to-execute-only-one-test-spec-with-angular-cli/58119974#58119974

Comment: I believe this is the best answer to this question now that angular has added glob matching via the include param https://stackoverflow.com/a/59723121/2002095

Answer (score 380, accepted):

I discovered that Jasmine allows you to prefix `describe` and `it` methods with an `f` (for focus):  `fdescribe` and `fit`.  If you use either of these, [Karma](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) will only run the relevant tests.  To focus the current file, you can just take the top level `describe` and change it to `fdescribe`.  If you use Jasmine prior to version 2.1, the focusing keywords are:  `iit` and `ddescribe`.

This example code runs just the first test:

```
// Jasmine versions >/=2.1 use 'fdescribe'; versions <2.1 use 'ddescribe'
fdescribe('MySpec1', function () {
    it('should do something', function () {
        // ...
    });
});

describe('MyOtherSpec', function () {
    it('should do something else', function () {
        // ...
    });
});
```

[Here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) is the Jasmine documentation on Focusing Specs, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8527786/212950) is a related SO article that provides additional thoughtful solutions.

Comment: Can't believe such important functionality is not more obvious and straightforward.

Comment: it works but it is not ideal because you need to change the source code and you can end up checking in the modified code in source control.

Comment: Please add links to [official documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html), when possible

Comment: The above documentation link is broken. Here is the new [link](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/global.html#fdescribe)

Comment: Ok fdescribe is one option. But what about if project has 100spec files? And you want to run just one spec file? ng test compile all files...

Comment: This is kind of answer you could only get on Stack Overflow and not in an official documentation.

Answer (score 108):

This can be achieved these days via the `include` option.
https://angular.io/cli/test#options

It's a glob match, so as an example:

```
ng test --include='**/someFolder/*.spec.ts'
```

I can't find it in the [8.1.0 release notes](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v8.1.0), but @Swoox mentions below this is a feature after cli version `8.1.0`. Thanks for figuring that out.

Comment: This seems like a recent update. Might want to include what version is needed. CLI 8.1 is needed.

Comment: Seems to be removed in v9.1 :(

Comment: I just tested this in CLI v9.1.0 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Works in CLI v10.0.4 too

Comment: Works with CLI v12

Comment: Works with Angular CLI: 13.0.4 too

Answer (score 44):

I found that `ng test` has an additional option `--include` which you can use in order to be able to run test for a single file, or for a particular directory, or for a bunch of files:

```
// one file
npm run test -- --include src/app/components/component/component-name.component.spec.ts

// directory or bunch of files
npm run test -- --include src/app/components
```

[ng cli docs](https://angular.io/cli/test)

Comment: Angular 9 - it seems to have been removed

Comment: No, it's still available in NG 9.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. It's even still available in Angular 11, according to my tests.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be there in angular 14. Or is there something else going on

Comment: The double double dashes are important here.

Answer (score 40):

It's worth mentioning that you can disable particular test without commenting by `xdescribe` and `xit`

```
xdescribe('Hello world', () => { 
  xit('says hello', () => { 
    expect(helloWorld())
        .toEqual('Hello world!');
  });
});
```

And as somebody already said if you want to focus on some test then `fdescribe` and `fit`

```
fdescribe('Hello world', () => { 
  fit('says hello', () => { 
    expect(helloWorld())
        .toEqual('Hello world!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 17):

You can go to `src/test.ts` and can change the following line:

`const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);`

to

`const context = require.context('./', true, /**yourcomponent.component**\.spec\.ts$/);`

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking, this sounds like the most correct answer even though most questions on how to do this have the problem solved by using fit and fdescribe. There is a git issue to accomplish this more easily in Karma: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1507. Ideally, though not simply, we could configure Karma so we could make changes to one test, and then just click on it in the browser to rerun it with the update.

Answer (score 12):

#### Visual Studio Code Extension

The easiest way is to use the [vscode-test-explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-test-explorer) extension along with its child [angular-karma-test-explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=raagh.angular-karma-test-explorer) and [jasmine-test-adapter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-jasmine-test-adapter), you'll get a list of current test to run one by one if you want:

[image]

This is the same answer I gave at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525936/1657465), there's some more details there.

---

**UPDATE DEC/2021**: Angular Karma Test Explorer [has been deprecated](https://github.com/Raagh/angular-karma_test-explorer/commit/3748499fb078161f69829b1b66aff751d14cea8c), please consider using [Karma Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lucono.karma-test-explorer) instead

Answer (score 7):

In Angular 9 I have had luck with the following:

If you want to test a specific file:

```sh
ng test --test-file=path/to/your/file.component.spec.ts
```

If you have multiple projects in your Angular project and/or are using NX, you can specify an Angular project to test:

```
ng test project-name
```

---

---

You can also use

```
ng test --testNamePattern componentname
```

for something like `path/to/your/component/componentname.spec.ts`.  This will scan every file in every project, and is slower.

---

<strike>If you want to test only what has changed since your last commit (using git or other version control)</strike>

```
ng test --only-changed
```

Not working in vanilla Angular.

Comment: I tried to use --only-changed But it is showing an Invalid option, I have gone through the Angular documentation and there is no such option defined. Could you please add some dummy project where it is working?

Comment: --Only-changed does not exist in angular cli, please provide reference to angular source and documentation providing this feature

Comment: Does `ng test -- --only-changed` work for either of you?  

We use NX for our Angular mono-repo, and it may have modified the ng commands. We are also using testing library with angular, which may have also changed things.

Answer (score 5):

Using

```
ng test --main file.spec.ts
```

Answer (score 5):

Get the relative path for your test file & provide like this

```
ng test --include=src\app\app.component.spec.ts
```

It works for me!!

Comment: ng test --include src\app\app.component.spec.ts works as well

Answer (score 3):

You must have to go `src/test.ts` and can change the following line number code 18:

```
//Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

to

```
//Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /testing.component\.spec\.ts$/);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the answer. Your question thread did help me a lot. But, Some point was ambiguous. Especially, If you run the below CLI command.

```
npm run test -- --include src/app/component/your.component.spec.ts
```

It will run the single test file, but after running the test, the test browser will be closed immediately, you can't watch your test file due to the missing watch flag. Therefore you have to provide the watch flag as true value. I figured it out that the below CLI command is working fine with the watch flag.

```
ng test --watch=true "--include" "src/app/components/your.component.spec.ts"
```

Comment: This is not single test

Comment: Following helped me Riyad, thanks: ng test --watch=true --include 'src/app/shared/helper/data-override-helper.spec.ts'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ IDE you can install the ' Karma ' plugin and run specs individually by clicking the ' run ' icon next to the spec test

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Why make it so hard?

- run `ng test`
- **Open the link** shown in the console:

[image]

- On the top right, click on `Debug`:

[image]

- **Click on the test** you want to solo run:

[image]

- To re-run the test, **refresh the browser window** (e.g. with <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

**For JetBrains WebStorm Users Only**

I don't have `ng` installed globally so cannot run `ng test ...` from the command line. And I can't install it either as it could mess up with my existing codebase's Angular version. I am using [JetBrains WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/) IDE and in it you can just right click the spec file and run the test.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

Works if you specify your spec file as parameter.

For example:

```
ng test foo.spec.ts
```

Comment: Can you specify which version are you using? Not working with 1.7.x

Comment: It did not work as is for me either.   But I modified it to work with the  --main option before the path to the spec file.   I used an absolute path with forward slashes.  Have not tried a relative path.  Using Angular 6.   Not sure if it is the best solution, but it seems to work for me.