# Angular 9 how to run a single spec file when using Jest?

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132933/running-a-single-test-file/52333560) does not hold the answer for Angular 9/Jest, so looking for an up-to-date one.

Although [the docs](https://angular.io/cli/test) do mention it:

```
--include
```

It fails

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use

```
ng test -f <ComponentName>
```

where `<ComponentName>` is the actual name of the component, not the path to it and not the name of the spec file, eg:

```
ng test -f HomeComponent
```

More info on angular github repo [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17689). It explains that using Jest in Angular adds a custom builder, so that is why `--include` is not supported.

Comment: Does not work for me, returns Unknown option: 'HomeComponent'

Comment: What partially helped is ng test --testNamePattern="HomeComponent" where HomeComponent is the name of the test suite, not the name of the component. It still runs all the files but skips test suites that do not match the provided name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try installing same version of Jest globally which is present in your `package.json`. Using this command -

```
npm i -g jest@xx.yy.zz
```

Replace xx.yy.zz with the version mentioned in `package.json`. Then run this command to test single file.

```
jest -f "shared.service.spec.ts"
```

Should work for a single file but still if you want to run all tests in one directory or folder use this command -

```
jest --testPathPattern=src/app/shared/components
```

OR

Simply run it from node_modules of your current angular project. Run these commands from your angular root folder.

```
./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js -f shared.service.spec.ts 


./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --testPathPattern=src/app/shared/components
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't wish to install Jest globally as I have many Angular projects all using different versions of Angular and different versions of Jest.

Comment: In that case you can use - 
./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js -f shared.service.spec.ts
./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js  --testPathPattern=src/app/shared/components

Comment: Thanks again but it seems I have to use "ng test" -> Jest on its own does not recognise all the decorators used by Angular and just throws errors on every test.